# How to write multiple environment environment variables in one line?

Tags: command-line, capistrano

I'm using capistrano to deploy code to my hosts. If I want to run `cap roll HOSTS=server1, server2, ...`, what delimiter do I use between the server names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it about right, it's the comma. The whitespace is your problem. Try quoting:

```
cap roll HOSTS="server1, server2, server3"
```

or just don't use whitespace, and you won't need to quote.

```
cap roll HOSTS=server1,server2,server3
```

Alternatively, if the set of servers you're deploying to is defined as a role (and it probably should be), you can use the ROLES environment variable.

```
cap roll ROLES=myrole
```

or if you want to invoke on multiple roles at once, they can also be specified in the same style as the HOSTS variable:

```
cap roll ROLES=myrole1,myrole2,myrole3
```

(Assuming you're using Bash here--I've never had to run cap from another shell, so this may not apply if you're using something unusual like the windows shell)